# MySQL Replace Syntax -- wrap specific piece of text

Tags: mysql

Within a table, there is a params row that has some JSON encoded data -- as such:

```
{"categories":211,"singleCatOrdering":"","menu-anchor_title":"","menu-anchor_css":"","menu_image":"","menu_text":1,"page_title":"","show_page_heading":0,"page_heading":"","pageclass_sfx":"","menu-meta_description":"","menu-meta_keywords":"","robots":"","secure":0}
```

What I need to do is wrap `[]` around the `categories` parameter - to look as such:

```
{"categories":[211],"singleCatOrdering":"","menu-anchor_title":"","menu-anchor_css":"","menu_image":"","menu_text":1,"page_title":"","show_page_heading":0,"page_heading":"","pageclass_sfx":"","menu-meta_description":"","menu-meta_keywords":"","robots":"","secure":0}
```

I have tried the following (and a bunch of other failed ones) with no-dice:

```
UPDATE j17_menu SET params = REPLACE(params,'"categories":%,','"categories":[%],') WHERE component_id = 10021;
```

Am I possibly using the wildcard option wrong? Any nudges in the right direction would be a huge help. Thanks!

Comment: Is the second parameter always "singleCatOrdering"?  If so use a two replaces, one for the first square bracket and one for the last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one will work independent of the context

```
UPDATE j17_menu 
SET params=CONCAT (
    SUBSTR(params,1,LOCATE('"categories":',params)),
    '"categories":[',
    substr(
        params,
        LOCATE('"categories":',params)+13,
        LOCATE(',',params,LOCATE('"categories":',params))-LOCATE('"categories":',params)-13
    ),
    ']',
    substr(params,LOCATE(',',params,LOCATE('"categories":',params)))
)
WHERE component_id = 10021;
```